# remote contract function call with solidity

Tags: solidity, external-api, interfaces

I've deployed this very simple Contract:

```
contract Contract1 
{
   function myfunction(uint param1) public returns (uint)
   {
       return param1+1;
   }
}
```

Now, I've deployed a second contract:

```
interface Contract1Interface
{
    function myfunction(uint) external returns (uint);
}

contract Contract2   
{
   event log(string msg);

   Contract1Interface c = Contract1Interface(0x...deploymentadress_of_contract1);
   uint ret;
   bytes public data;

   function test1() public
   {
      // COMPILATION ERROR: try ret=c.myfunction(param) {  } catch {  }
      try c.myfunction(param) {  } catch {  }
   }
   
   function test2() public
   {  
     bool success;
     (success, data) = address(c).call{value: 0 ether}(abi.encodeWithSignature("myfunction(uint)", 5));

     if (success) {
         emit log("ok");
     } else {
         emit log("nok");
     } 
   }
   
   function test3() public
   {
     bool success;
     (success, data) = address(c).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("myfunction(uint)", 6));

     if (success) {
         emit log("ok");
     } else {
         emit log("nok");
     } 
   }
```

I have 4 questions:

- Is it a good practice to declare Contract1Interface this way ? We can imagine a situation where Contract2's developper do not have Contract1 source code. This developper only knows the functions signature (interface). Or is there a best way to do that ?
- in test1 function, i cannot fetch returned value for myfunction. If i add ret=, i get a compilation error.
- in test2 and test3 functions, success is equal to false. I do not understand why the call fails
- In test2 and test3 functions, how can i "decode" data variable to uint ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try to replace `5` and `6` with `uint(5)` and `uint(6)`.

Comment: Thanks but i got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types `uint` and `uint256` are identical (the former is just an alias of the latter).

However, the strings `"uint"` and `"uint256"` are obviously **not** identical.

Hence your attempt to call `myfunction(uint256)` using the encoded signature (i.e., the hash of) `"myfunction(uint)"` is wrong.

So to begin with, change the string `"uint"` to `"uint256"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to declare Contract1Interface this way?

This is acceptable.

Contract A can provide the interface and this can help ensure the interface description is correct:

```
contract IA {
  function doSomething() external view returns(unit);
}

contract A is IA {
  ...
}
```

Now, contract IA could be shared so that contract B will be confident they are using the correct interface.

> We can imagine a situation where Contract2's developer do not have Contract1 source code. This developer only knows the signature of the function (interface). Or is there a best way to do that?

If contract B's author doesn't have the code for IA and A then, in practice, there are other, bigger concerns. What you have done is workable.

> in test1 function, i cannot fetch returned value for myfunction. If i add ret=, i get a compilation error.

> in test2 and test3 functions, success is equal to false. I do not understand why the call fails

> In test2 and test3 functions, how can i "decode" data variable to uint ?

These are separate questions, each of which is a little rabbit hole of its own. Please post one question at a time.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you've missed the main point (see my answer).